# exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15404, State

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am so new to Service Broker. I found a simple example as you can see here:

```
CREATE DATABASE ServiceBrokerTest
GO
USE ServiceBrokerTest
GO

-- Enable Service Broker
ALTER DATABASE ServiceBrokerTest SET ENABLE_BROKER
GO

-- Create Message Type
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE SBMessage
VALIDATION = NONE
GO

-- Create Contract
CREATE CONTRACT SBContract
(SBMessage SENT BY INITIATOR)
GO

-- Create Send Queue
CREATE QUEUE SBSendQueue
GO

-- Create Receive Queue
CREATE QUEUE SBReceiveQueue
GO

-- Create Send Service on Send Queue
CREATE SERVICE SBSendService
ON QUEUE SBSendQueue (SBContract)
GO

-- Create Receive Service on Receive Queue
CREATE SERVICE SBReceiveService
ON QUEUE SBReceiveQueue (SBContract)
GO

-- Begin Dialog using service on contract
DECLARE @SBDialog uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(128)
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @SBDialog
FROM SERVICE SBSendService
TO SERVICE 'SBReceiveService'
ON CONTRACT SBContract
WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF

-- Send messages on Dialog
SET @Message = N'Very First Message';
SEND ON CONVERSATION @SBDialog
MESSAGE TYPE SBMessage (@Message)

SET @Message = N'Second Message';
SEND ON CONVERSATION @SBDialog
MESSAGE TYPE SBMessage (@Message)

SET @Message = N'Third Message';
SEND ON CONVERSATION @SBDialog
MESSAGE TYPE SBMessage (@Message)
GO

-- View messages from Receive Queue
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM SBReceiveQueue
GO

-- Receive messages from Receive Queue
RECEIVE TOP(1) CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM SBReceiveQueue
GO

-- Receive messages from Receive Queue
RECEIVE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM SBReceiveQueue
GO
```

This link [example link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/) but when I run the query it returns zero records - why?

[image]

Comment: The example seems to be working. Check that there are no uncommitted transactions on the connection. Also, you can have a look at `sys.conversation_endpoints` and `sys.transmission_queue` as a starting point for diagnostics.

Comment: @RogerWolf you mean i execute this :select * from sys.conversation_endpoints?

Comment: yes. It would also be a good idea to check the documentation on these system views, regarding what they mean and how you should interpret their contents.

Comment: @RogerWolf i see this error An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15404, State: 19. Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'UNION\TFS-Symfa', error code 0x5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally execute this code and it works

```
sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```